# PHP graphql get all records for the past 24 hours

Tags: php, recursion, graphql, cloudflare

I have my initial graphQL query working, where the aim is to get the total amount of requests that happened in the past 24 hours returned in ascending order.

Script:

```
public function get() {
   
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $startDate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $startDate = $this->dateManageMinutes($startDate, "- 24 hour");
    $endDate = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
    $this->getHttpRequest($startDate, $endDate);

    $response["data"] = $this->cdnRequest;

    return (new ResourceResponse($response, 200))->addCacheableDependency(array('#cache' => array('max-age' => 0)));

}

public function getHttpRequest($startDate, $endDate) {

    $query = <<<'GRAPHQL'
        {
            viewer {
                zones(filter: { zoneTag: $zone }) {
                    httpRequestsAdaptive(
                        filter: {
                            datetime_geq: $datetime_geq
                            datetime_leq: $datetime_lt
                        }
                        limit: 10000
                        orderBy: [
                            datetime_ASC
                        ]
                    ) {
                        device: clientDeviceType
                        clientIP: clientIP
                        clientRefererHost: clientRefererHost
                        clientRequsestPath: clientRequestPath
                        date: date
                        datetime: datetime
                        originResponseStatus: originResponseStatus
                        userAgent: userAgent
                        userAgentOS: userAgentOS
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    GRAPHQL;

    $variables = [
        "zone" => $this->zone,
        "datetime_geq" => $startDate,
        "datetime_lt" => $endDate,
    ];

    $payload = json_encode(['query' => $query, 'variables' => $variables], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

    $headers = [
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer $this->token"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/graphql");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

    $curlResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($curlResponse, 0, $header_size);

    $responseData = json_decode(substr($curlResponse, $header_size), true)['data']['viewer']['zones'][0]["httpRequestsAdaptive"];

    array_push($this->cdnRequest, $responseData);

    return $responseData;
}
```

Result sample:

```
{
    "clientRequsestPath": "\/sites\/default\/files\/2023-03\/Recharge.svg",
    "datetime": "2023-05-14T17:44:32Z",
},
{
    "clientRequsestPath": "\/sites\/default\/files\/2023-05\/instagram.svg",
    "datetime": "2023-05-14T17:44:32Z",
}
```

**Problem:** Cloudflare only responds with a maximum of 10000. However, I want all the data for the past 24 hours.

To do this, I thought of calling the getHttpRequest method recursively, so that I can continue making the requests based on the last date time given until the end date is finally reached.

So I adjusted the script by adding the following to the end of getHttpRequest method:

```
$lastItemDate = $responseData[9999]["datetime"];
// takes into account If it has 100000 items or the date returned by the last item is still less than the current date.
if((count($responseData) == 10000) || ($lastItemDate < $endDate)) {
    $this->getHttpRequest($startDate, $endDate);
}
```

Result: the request seems to be going in an infinite loop.

**Question:** How do I query this endpoint and retrieve all the date despite the fact that the API only returns 10000 at a time?

Am open to suggestions as I've been on this one for a while now.

Comment: Looping doesn't sound right because you won't know from where until when. But am open to suggestions with more context if possible.

Comment: The limit was intentional because the API requires it, where the maximum is 10000.

Comment: Did you try [pagination](https://developers.cloudflare.com/analytics/graphql-api/features/pagination/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I saw the page doc, but it doesn't give me a clue on how to use even when I see it now.